# How I can build AST tree for arithmetics expressions?

Tags: powershell, abstract-syntax-tree

I've gathered you all here to ask you just one simple question.
I need to build AST tree.

> For example I have expression 22*x+(z–5)*2.
>   How can I make this easier with powershell?

Comment: Please edit the question and explain with more details which part are you having problems with. Building an AST (language agnostic) or doing that in Powershell (language dependent.)

Comment: Yes, How can I do that in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually build the AST - PowerShell will do it for you!

Wrap the expression in a scriptblock (has to be syntactically valid PowerShell of course):

```
$AST = {22*$x+($z–5)*2}.Ast
```

Voila, `$AST.Endblock` now holds the AST root element of your expression.

You can also construct the AST by explicitly passing the expression to `Parser.ParseInput()` as a string:

```
$AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput('22*$x+($z–5)*2', [ref]$null, [ref]$null)
```

Comment: And how can I show steps of evaluation?
1) z-5
2) (z-5)*2 ...and etc

Comment: Before I update my answer, can you please expand your question with what you're trying to achieve exactly, and why?

Comment: like this 
https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2009/02/05/evaluating-expressions-part-3-building-the-ast/